# Having trouble in C# Interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, interface, ienumerable

I'm trying to understand the -why- of this ... and I'm really struggling to grasp the concept of what I'm telling the compiler to do when I use an IInterface syntax.  Can anyone explain it in a "this is what's going on" way?

Anyway ... my main question is....

What is the difference between

```
public IEnumerable<string> MyMethod() {...}
```

and

```
public string MyMethod() : IEnumerable {...}
```

Why would you use one over the other?

Comment: Your second example isn't valid code. (I'm assuming you mean C# - it would be worth tagging the question.) If you can make both examples valid, we'll tell you the remaining differences.

Answer (score 4):

```
public string MyMethod() : IEnumerable {...}
```

Will not compile, that's one difference.

But you could have

```
public class MyClass : IEnumerable<string> {...}
```

And then

```
public IEnumerable<string> MyMethod() 
{
   MyClass mc = new MyClass();
   return mc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say `public IEnumerable<string> MyMethod() {...}` , you are declaring a method which returns some instance that implements `IEnumerable<string>`.  This instance might be an array of string, a `List<string>`, or some type that you make.

When you say `public class MyClass : IEnumerable<string> {...}`, you are declaring a type which implements `IEnumerable<string>`.  An instance of MyClass could be returned by MyMethod.

Answer (score 0):

the first is a valid method declaration, as long as it is living in a Class
ie

```
class MyClass 
{
    public IEnumerable<string> MyMethod() {...}
}
```

the second is not valid C# and will not compile.  It is close to a Class declaration, tho.

```
class MyClass : IEnumerable<string>
{

}
```